# Как использовать boost который установил в ручную?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, boost

У меня возможно глупый вопрос но все же, я поставил руками boost_1_78_0:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr && ./b2 stage threading=multi link=shared
./b2 install threading=multi link=shared && ln -svf detail/sha1.hpp /usr/include/boost/uuid/sha1.hpp
```

Все вроде как на месте:

```
./b2 install threading=multi link=shared
```

Тесты:

```
pushd tools/build/test; python3 test_all.py; popd
/usr/boost_1_78_0/tools/build/test /usr/boost_1_78_0
    === Test summary ===
    PASS: 166
    FAIL: 0
    
/usr/boost_1_78_0
```

Как теперь использовать этот буст?
Просто когда я смотрю версию, допустим вот такими способами:

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.71.0.0ubuntu2

sudo aptitude show boost
E: Не удалось найти пакет boost
```

Далее пытаюсь собрать один проект, у меня выдает вот это:

```
cd _android && cmake \
               -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
               -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21 \
               -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK= ..
-- [hunter] Calculating Toolchain-SHA1
-- [hunter] Calculating Config-SHA1
-- [hunter] HUNTER_ROOT: /root/.hunter
-- [hunter] [ Hunter-ID: 95c4 | Toolchain-ID: cb3d | Config-ID: 6ca7 ]
-- [hunter] BOOST_ROOT: /root/.hunter/_Base/95c47c9/cb3d9e0/6ca7930/Install (ver.: 1.76.0)
-- [hunter] BOOST_ROOT: /root/.hunter/_Base/95c4/cb3d/6ca7/Install (ver.: 1.76.0)
//тут программа просто подвисает, не ложится, ничего, просто ждет
```

Возможно тут дело вовсе не в бусте, но, буду рад любым объяснениям, спасибо, к сожалению название проекта сказать не могу но там видимо используется cmake HunterGate который помогает билдить проект и находить нужные либы, это то как я понял, возможно я не прав

Если собирать в обычном debug виде:

```
cd _debug && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- [hunter] Calculating Toolchain-SHA1
-- [hunter] Calculating Config-SHA1
-- [hunter] HUNTER_ROOT: /root/.hunter
-- [hunter] [ Hunter-ID: 95c4 | Toolchain-ID: cb3d | Config-ID: 2df3 ]
-- [hunter] BOOST_ROOT: /root/.hunter/_Base/95c4/cb3d/2df3/Install (ver.: 1.76.0)
```

Comment: 1) не надо выполнять `./b2 install`, это только засоряет систему 2) для использования из-под андроида его надо будет собрать кросс-компиляторами из тулчейна андроида

Comment: @user7860670 но ведь даже с сборкой в debug виде выдает тоже самое, мне кажется на данном этапе дело не в том что сборка буста не под android.
Обновил вопрос

Comment: "Установленные" в убунте компоненты в сборке под андроид будут игнорироваться. Без сборки под андроид он все равно не заработает.

Comment: @user7860670 хорошо, а что по поводу обычной debug сборки?

Comment: А тут никакой разницы, хоть debug, хоть release.

Comment: @user7860670 правильно ли я понял, мне нужно собрать этот проект кросс компиляторами из тулчейна андрода и подругому он не заработает, при том что эта библиотека изначально написана НЕ под android, а под linux, а я пытаюсь сделать сборку под android в своих личных целях чтобы использовать в другом проекте.

Comment: Естественно. Чтобы что-то работало под андроид это придется собирать используя тулчейны android.